# AnimationDrawable doesn't work on Samsung S3 mini

Tags: android, animation, adt, animationdrawable

i've got a problem:
The AnimationDrawable in my app works perfectly on my Nexus 4 (Android 4.4.2) but on my Samsung Galaxy S3 (4.1.2) mini it doesn't start. Anyone there who knows how to solve that problem?

Greetings Nils

My Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final AnimationDrawable ad = (AnimationDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ad);
    ad.run();
}
```

the AnimationDrawable xml-file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_1" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_2" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_3" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_4" android:duration="500" />

</animation-list>
```

Comment: Call `start()` instead of `run()`.

Comment: ad hangs in nowhere, it isn't set to any View so how can it work?

Comment: Yes it is. In my layout.xml it is set to an imageview

Comment: try to Log.d the hash code of ad and imageview.getDrawable() and you will see that they're two different objects, try imageview. getDrawable().start()

Comment: But in my other app the AnimationDrawabke is part of an layer-list which is set as scr of an imageButton. I there a way to get it like that?

Comment: sure,  see LayerDrawable docs

Comment: what do I have to use as index in getDrawable? If I have two items in the LayerList which index is which one?